# Nothing is accessible: HTTP Error 500.19

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-express

I have an ASP.NET MVC web project, it's received from a git repository (so it's not created on my PC).
When I run it, it acts like it does not see neither .css, nor .js, nor .html files.
I tried to reaach any of those files directly from the URL and when I do it, I get HTTP Error 500.19 
It seems to me that there is something wrong with the IIS Express settings.
Please advise how could I fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 500.19 simply means your config is invalid.

Comment: how it could be invalid on one machine and valid on the others?

Comment: due to the extensibility of IIS, that's perfectly normal.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I also checked whether config is a valid xml and it is.

Comment: a config file can be valid XML and full of invalid configuration. So make sure you paste the contents I ask for. I don't ask for a thing without a reason. If you are not willing to paste, do it your way and I won't bother.